# Find an integer $0 \le x \le 721$ such that $680x \equiv 1\pmod {721}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Find an integer $0 \le x \le 721$ such that $680x \equiv 1\pmod {721}$

Also we need to do it for $680x \equiv 679\pmod{721}$.

Very unsure on how to go about this.

Comment: Do you know the Euclidean Algorithm? Given two integers $m,n$, it ouputs their GCD=r in a way that allows you to find a linear combination $am+bn=r$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $680=2^3\cdot5\cdot17$, and the inverses of $2$ and $5$ are easy to compute. For $17$, note that $17\cdot43=731\equiv 10$ mod $721$ to find the inverse of $17$. Using these facts you can find the inverse of the product $680=2^3\cdot5\cdot 17$.

Next, if you know $680\cdot x=1$, think about modifying $x$ in a simple way to obtain the product equivalent to $679$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $680$ and $721$ are coprime, so use Euclidean algorithm to find integers $x $ and $y $ such that $680x+721y=1$. The resulting $x $ may already suit you, if not - reduce it modulo $721$.

For the second part, multiply $x $ from the first part by $679$ modulo $721$.

I will leave it to you to fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 0):

We have $721=7\cdot 103$, so if we can solve $680x\equiv 1\pmod 7$ and $680x\equiv 1\pmod {103}$, then we can use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to put those solutions together.

$680x\equiv 1\pmod 7\implies x\equiv 1\pmod 7$, because $7|679$.

$680x\equiv 1\pmod {103} \implies 62x\equiv 1\pmod {103}\implies x\equiv 5\pmod{103}$.

That last congruence is solvable via the Euclidean algorithm.

Now, we want to find something that is congruent to $5$, mod $103$, and to $1$, mod $7$. The easiest way is probably to start with $5$, and repeatedly add $103$ until we have something that has the right mod$7$ congruence:

$5+103=108\equiv_7 3\\
108+103=211\equiv_7 1.$

So we have $211$ for our first solution. Checking: $680\times 211=143480=199\times 721+1$.

Now, we can solve the second congruence by just mutiplying $211$ by $679$:

$211\times 679=143269\equiv 511\pmod{721}$.

Checking: $680\times 511=347480=481\times 721+679$.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that

$$ 721 \cdot (-199) + 680 \cdot 211 = 1, $$
  $$ 680 \cdot 211 = 1 +  721 \cdot 199, $$
 $$ 680 \cdot 211 \equiv 1 \pmod{  721} \; .  $$

I just wrote 721/680 as a continued fraction, that is all. neighboring "convergents" give crossed products as $\pm 1.$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

$$ \frac{ 721 }{ 680 } = 1 +  \frac{ 41 }{ 680 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 680 }{ 41 } = 16 +  \frac{ 24 }{ 41 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 41 }{ 24 } = 1 +  \frac{ 17 }{ 24 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 24 }{ 17 } = 1 +  \frac{ 7 }{ 17 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 17 }{ 7 } = 2 +  \frac{ 3 }{ 7 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 7 }{ 3 } = 2 +  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 3 }{ 1 } = 3 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 } $$ 
 Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccccc}
 & & 1 & & 16 & & 1 & & 1 & & 2 & & 2 & & 3 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 1 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 17 }{ 16 }   & &   \frac{ 18 }{ 17 }   & &   \frac{ 35 }{ 33 }   & &   \frac{ 88 }{ 83 }   & &   \frac{ 211 }{ 199 }   & &   \frac{ 721 }{ 680 }  
 \end{array}
 $$ 
 $$  $$

$$ 721 \cdot 199 - 680 \cdot 211 = -1 $$